# Proving that a function is discontinuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

In my assignment I have to prove that the following function is discontinuous:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x-1&\text{if }x\notin\Bbb Q\\x^2&\text{if }x \in \Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

I have to prove that in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

I have some sort of beginning, I have to prove that some $\epsilon >0$ exists such that for every $\delta>0$ if $|x-x_0|<\delta \to |f(x)-f(x_0)| >\ \epsilon$

I don't really how to continue from here - I thought about picking $\epsilon=0.01$ and show that $|2x-4|$ is always bigger than that if I pick the right $\delta$ - but how do I show it?
I have thought that since $\Bbb Q$ is a Dense set I can always choose the $\delta$ I want but... I don't know how.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Just a cautionary note: this function is continuous at $x=1$ while it is discontinuous at other points.

Comment: So you may recommend that I pick $\epsilon=1$?

Comment: In fact, the function is even *differentiable* at $x=1$.

Comment: @Strants didn't study that yet, unfortunately.

Comment: I have thought that since $\Bbb Q$ is a Dense set I can always choose the $\delta$ I want but... I don't know how.

Comment: Have you studied the characterization of continuity in terms of sequences?

Comment: @EricAuld Yes, I have. In fact, the next question in my assignment is to prove the same question here, in terms of sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $x_0$ where $x_0^2 \neq 2x_0-1$ and consider two sequences approaching $x_0$, one consisting of only rational numbers, the other of only irrational numbers. To do it in terms of $\epsilon$ and $ \delta$, figure out the difference between $x_0^2$ and $2x_0 -1$ and make $\epsilon$ less than that.

Answer (score 1):

You state that

> I have to prove that some $\varepsilon > 0$ exists such that for every $\delta > 0$ if $|x-x_0|<\delta \to |f(x)-f(x_0)| >\ \varepsilon$

but this isn't the correct negation of the statement

> $f$ is continuous.

To find the correct negation, start with the definition of *continuity*, which is

> For every $x_0$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-x_0| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$.

Put more formally, this becomes

> $\forall x_0\quad\forall \varepsilon > 0\quad\exists \delta > 0\quad\forall x\quad:\quad |x-x_0| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon.$

To negate that, we prefix the statement with a negation ($\lnot$), and then use the rules

- $\lnot\forall x\;\ldots$ is the same as $\exists x\;\lnot\ldots$
- $\lnot\exists x\;\ldots$ is the same as $\forall x\;\lnot\ldots$
- $\lnot(A \rightarrow B)$ is the same as $A \land \lnot B$ (i.e. the negation of $A$ implies $B$ is that there is a case where $A$ holds but $B$ doesn't).

Applying that to the definition of continuity yields

> $\exists x_0\quad\exists \varepsilon > 0\quad\forall \delta > 0\quad\exists x\quad:\quad |x-x_0| < \delta\;\land\;|f(x)-f(x_0)|\geq\varepsilon$

So what you have to do is to first pick some $x_0$ and some $\varepsilon$. Then you have to show that for every $\delta > 0$ you can find some $x$ which satisfies $|x-x_0|<\delta$, but for which $|f(x)-f(x_0)| \geq \varepsilon$.

In other words, for some fixed $x_0$ and $\varepsilon$, you need to find $x$ which lie arbitrarily close to $x_0$, yet whose images under $f$ all lie at least $\varepsilon$ away from $f(x_0)$.

The problem with your statement is that you didn't correctly deal with the $\forall x$ in the definition of *continuity*, and failed to notice that it gets turned into an *existantial* quantifier in the negation. The way you stated the negation therefore seems to require that you find some $\delta$ such that for *all* $x$ closer than $\delta$ to $x_0$ the image under $f$ lies at least $\varepsilon$ away from $f(x_0)$.

But this is overly strict, and it fact impossible -- you can always pick $x=x_0$ (since then obviously $|x-x_0|=0 < \delta$ for every $\delta > 0$), and then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0<\varepsilon$ will always hold, regardless of whether $f$ is continuous or not.

In the correct negation, on the other hand, you see that you only need to find a *single* $x$ for every $\delta$. For your $f$, these $x$ will be irrational if $x_0$ is rational, and rational if $x_0$ is irrational. Note that you don't need to do both cases -- you can *choose* whatever value you like for $x_0$ (and also $\varepsilon$), because these quantities are under an existential quantifier in the negation of *continuity*.